# Convert a datetime value to time with 12hour system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I'm working on `ASP.NET MVC` project with `Entity Framework`.

I have a `Datetime` value received from `SQL Server database`, the **value inside database look like :**  `8/1/2020 10:00:00 AM`, and inside the `view` I want to get just the time part from the full date *( I want time showed with 12H system )* , so I try this :

**View :**

```
<tr>
    
<td>@item.DT_ABS.ToString("hh:mm tt")</td>
   
</tr>
```

**Result should be :**

```
10:00 AM
```

**Result I got :**

```
10:00
```

So please any help about this issue ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: var str = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"hh:mm tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));

https://dotnetfiddle.net/LtFHZP

Comment: @Mikael thank you this help me

Answer (score 0):

The solution that helped me is :

```
@item.DT_ABS.ToString("hh:mm tt",new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Comment: Try this one: @item.DT_ABS.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)